# How do i import SFML in CLion into C/C++ on Linux?

Tags: c++, clion

I am currently trying to run this generic starter code using the SFML library.

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
    sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }
        window.clear();
        window.draw(shape);
        window.display();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am running Linux (distro is arch) and im using the library from a .tar.gz i downloaded on SFML's website.
I believe the issue is with CMakeLists, but thats all i have figured out, as this is all very foreign to me.
Here is my CMakeLists file.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(untitled)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
add_executable(untitled main.cpp)

include_directories(/home/eggbladder/Downloads/SFML-2.6.1/include/)
target_link_libraries(untitled /home/eggbladder/Downloads/SFML-2.6.1/lib/)
```

I tried to run the code in CLion, and it ended up giving me all of these errors.

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccVwcfyP.o: warning: relocation against `_ZTVN2sf11CircleShapeE' in read-only section `.text._ZN2sf11CircleShapeD2Ev[_ZN2sf11CircleShapeD5Ev]'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccVwcfyP.o: in function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x78): undefined reference to `sf::String::String(char const*, std::locale const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x96): undefined reference to `sf::VideoMode::VideoMode(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int)'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0xc9): undefined reference to `sf::RenderWindow::RenderWindow(sf::VideoMode, sf::String const&, unsigned int, sf::ContextSettings const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x105): undefined reference to `sf::CircleShape::CircleShape(float, unsigned long)'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x113): undefined reference to `sf::Color::Green'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x11e): undefined reference to `sf::Shape::setFillColor(sf::Color const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x13c): undefined reference to `sf::Window::close()'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x155): undefined reference to `sf::WindowBase::pollEvent(sf::Event&)'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x17d): undefined reference to `sf::Color::Color(unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char)'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x19a): undefined reference to `sf::RenderTarget::clear(sf::Color const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x1b3): undefined reference to `sf::RenderStates::Default'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x1be): undefined reference to `sf::RenderTarget::draw(sf::Drawable const&, sf::RenderStates const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x1cd): undefined reference to `sf::Window::display()'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x1dc): undefined reference to `sf::WindowBase::isOpen() const'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x207): undefined reference to `sf::RenderWindow::~RenderWindow()'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x28c): undefined reference to `sf::RenderWindow::~RenderWindow()'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccVwcfyP.o: in function `sf::CircleShape::~CircleShape()':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN2sf11CircleShapeD2Ev[_ZN2sf11CircleShapeD5Ev]+0xf): undefined reference to `vtable for sf::CircleShape'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text._ZN2sf11CircleShapeD2Ev[_ZN2sf11CircleShapeD5Ev]+0x1d): undefined reference to `vtable for sf::CircleShape'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text._ZN2sf11CircleShapeD2Ev[_ZN2sf11CircleShapeD5Ev]+0x31): undefined reference to `sf::Shape::~Shape()'
/usr/bin/ld: warning: creating DT_TEXTREL in a PIE
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I expected the code to result in a basic, starter window.

Comment: "im using the library from a .tar.gz i downloaded on SFML's website" - Ehh, why? Why don't you just install SFML via `packman` how it's supposed to be done? It works just fine when installed *properly*.

Comment: in my attempts of fixing the issue myself, i downloaded it from the site and just put it in my downloads. its much easier than navigating the linux file directory and trying to remember where everything was installed to.

Comment: "its much easier than navigating the linux file directory and trying to remember where everything was installed to." - Ehh, *what*? You don't need to remember anything, you just do `packman -Syu sfml` and *boom*, there it is and works as it should.

Comment: Btw; what you show in the question are *linker* errors.

Comment: im assuming you are talking about `pacman -Ql sfml` and not `packman -Syu`. It prints a list of directories where SFML has files, which i then have to click to and check where they are. Im not too familiar with Linux yet, so its easier to just... go to downloads, then click the big folder that says SFML.

Comment: `target_link_libraries(untitled /home/eggbladder/Downloads/SFML-2.6.1/lib/)` is certainly not correct.  `target_link_libraries` supplies a list of libraries or targets not a folder.

Comment: @eggblader I very much meant `pacman -Syu sfml` which will update the packages on your system *and* install SFML. No further action required. All done. You can then use the latest version of SFML both for developing and running applications.

Comment: @drescherjm What should i do instead?

Comment: @JesperJuhl Unfortunately, that didnt work. I still get the same errors.

Comment: Btw; none of this has *anything* to do with clion.

Comment: Alright, i will remove CLion from the tags.

Comment: Did you actually _build_ SFML?  If you downloaded the source tarball it will need to be built first; then you can `target_link_library` with the full path.  As Jesper Juhl said though, it would be easier to just install it via pacman and then `find_package(SFML COMPONENTS graphics REQUIRED)` and `target_link_libraries(untitled sfml-graphics)`.

Comment: I did not build SFML, as i didnt know (how) to do that. 
It is installed in pacman, and adding the two commands results in what looks like the same error.

Comment: Ah, never mind, I see SFML ships a binary distribution, so doesn't need to be built.

Comment: what should i do to fix the errors that i am getting?